# align icons secondary menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

http://oncofigado.suryamkt.com.br/

Hello everybody

I've tried so much CSS to align these icons on the top of page, but it hasn't worked.
If anyone can help me, I'm so grateful.

[image]

This is the actual code, in each icon.

> .menu-item-74{        margin-top:10px;        margin-right:500px;         float:left;
>   }

Comment: Try align="top"

Comment: you want the icons on the left side?

Comment: because the icons are already on the top right in the link, but they are on the left in the image

Comment: try to use flex: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much control you have over editing your page but here is one solution that should work without forcing you change the HTML.

I'm only including the things I added on top of what you already have on the page.

For the #et-secondary-menu div :

```
width: 100%;
```

For the #et-secondary-nav ul :

```
width: 100%;
display: flex;
```

For the #menu-item-76 li :

```
flex: 1;
```

That should give you a responsive menu.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be fixed with only CSS. To get the image looking as wanted we need a structural HTML change as well.

**Solution**

---

This solution splits the top left and top right corners into their own `div`. Then it applies `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` to the parent container.

```
<div id="et-secondary-menu" style="float: none;">
  <div id="et-secondary-nav" class="menu" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
    <div>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-74"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-156" src="http://oncofigado.suryamkt.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/icones-facebook-dourado.png" alt="oncofigado-facebook" width="25" height="25"></a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-75"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-156" src="http://oncofigado.suryamkt.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/icones-instagram-dourado.png" alt="oncofigado-instagram" width="25" height="25"></a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-106"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-156" src="http://oncofigado.suryamkt.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/icones-youtube-dourado.png" alt="oncofigado-youtube" width="25" height="25"></a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-107"><a href="#"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-156" src="http://oncofigado.suryamkt.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/icone-whastapp-dourado.png" alt="oncofigado-whatsapp" width="25" height="25"></a></li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-76"><a href="#"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-156" src="http://oncofigado.suryamkt.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/agende-sua-consulta-1.jpg" alt="agende-sua-consulta"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Results**

---

[image]